# Database doesn't receive file extension

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm creating an profile picture upload system in PHP & MySQL. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the database does not include the extension of $db_file_name. How ever, when I echo the variable, it does show the extension in the string.

Also when I echo the sql, it does show the extension. So the problem is MySQL related.

Any idea's what the problem might be?

This is the query:

```
$db_file_name = "123456.jpg";

        // Move result into database
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET avatar='$db_file_name' WHERE email='$s_email' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql);
```

The database received the number without the extension (.jpg, .gif, .png). The datatype of the avatar column is VARCHAR(255) with a default value of NULL.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: 1) There's a potential for SQL injection here.  2) File names aren't unique in this code, this could overwrite another user's file without warning.

Comment: Hello, yes I am aware of the potential SQL injection, I will add the check later on. But for now I just want it to work. And since a profile photo is uploaded to a user it's own directory, there should be no problem with duplication. Later on I'm going to add a function that cleans the directory before putting a new file in it.

Comment: Can you echo `$sql` to see its runtime value?  Does it include the file extension?  Does executing that same query manually on the database produce the same result?

Comment: @David When I echo $sql it does contain the extension. When I run the query in phpMyAdmin SQL then it does not receive the extension, so I guess there is a problem with MySQL adding the string to the database (might be because of the dot?). Maybe I should use another datatype?

Comment: I wouldn't think that would be an issue, strings can contain dots.  What is the exact query?  What is the schema of the table?  If executing the query manually is producing the same result then at the very least we can simplify this question to a single `UPDATE` query and a single table definition.

Comment: @David The exact query is: UPDATE users SET avatar='504241.png' WHERE email='asd@asd.asd' LIMIT 1

Comment: How exactly are you *confirming* the inserted data? Have you tried alternative methods as well?

Comment: Although you've already said it, could you go back and view the table structure one more time and double- or triple-check that the column `avatar` is `VARCHAR(255)`? It's just really coincidental that numeric-dot-string gets stored as numeric...

Comment: What if you do the same query in phpMyAdmin but instead of `'123456.jpg'` you do `'foo.jpg'` so there is no numeric involved. (Don't go back to your PHP - let's stay within phpMyAdmin for this test.)

Comment: @PeterBowers The problem was how the collation was set, once I set it to utf8_general_ci, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem.

The collation of the column was latin1_swedish_ci. 
Once I set it to utf8_general_ci, the problem was solved.

Comment: Not that this should have made any difference, unless you're using some really weird `.` character.